# Why do we get 406, when passing parsed json through ajax from mobile web?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, json, ajax

I was making an ajax call to my rails controller method which responds with

```
respond_to do |format|
 format.js {render <js.erb file>}
```

from my client side html file I was saving the original parameters (ie. the parameters which were passed to the method from where ajax call is made) like this -

```
input#original_params type='hidden' value=params.to_json
```

Now before making the ajax call, I appended a couple of more elements in that param json in my script

```
var params = JSON.parse($('#original_params').val());
params.key1 = value1;
params.key2 = value2;
```

then I made the following ajax call -

```
$.ajax({
        type: 'post',
        url: '<url_to_method>',
        data: params,
        success: function(value){
         //do something
        }
      });
```

This setup was working good when I tested from the browser in my computer, but when I tried testing on my mobile's chrome browser, the server responded with a 406 not acceptable.
To solve this issue I had to do this -

```
var original_params = JSON.parse($('#original_params').val());
var params = {}
params.key1 = value1;
params.key2 = value2;
params.key3 = original_params['key1']
params.key4 = original_params['key2']
params.key5 = original_params['key3']
```

But I am not sure why this worker and what was the actual issue, can anyone help ?

Comment: so, originally you use `params.payment_mode = value;` - and then you use `params.payment_mode = this.value;` ... what is `this` in the context of your code? **and now you've edited the question to make my comment redundant**

Comment: this is inside an onchange method of radio box, so `this` will be the radio box element

Comment: I have edited to make it more generic now

Comment: given the code you've posted now, you originally send an object with key1, key2, and key3 only (based on what you now send, param has key1, key2 and key3 - maybe more, but who knows) ... and you now send an object with key1, key2, key3, key4 and key5 ... so you send a completely different object now! Your edit has resulted in less clarity

Comment: earlier I was using the same object from the input element and just adding values to it, but later I created a completely new object and picked the values from the element value into this object

Comment: I recall the original question - I don't understand why you've made the generic code harder to read ... may I suggest, keeping it generic, you use newkey1 and newkey2 for value1 and value2, and assign key1 to key1, key2 to key2 etc - I think it would be less odd looking :p

Comment: the description of 406 is `The HTTP 406 Not Acceptable client error response code indicates that a response matching the list of acceptable values defined in Accept-Charset and Accept-Language cannot be served.` - perhaps your server is sending a 406 when it should be sending something else? ... or, more likely ... **Accept-Charset** **Accept-Language** ... looks like your mobile is sending different request headers than your desktop browser, and the server doesn't know how to speak that language/charset - though, that doesn't explain why changing the object like you do would fix this issue